# Is there a way to convert cached webex files to some other format?

Tags: ffmpeg, webex

How can I convert webex files in the temp cache to generally usable media formats?

Answer (score 0):

Cisco provide a number of tools for converting WebEx formats.

http://www.webex.co.uk/support/downloads.html

I don't know if the files that are cached are sufficient ; these tools are intended for a full recording, I think. But this may be the closest thing available.

Comment: I don't think part of this answer addresses the from cache component